# Can we use force.com site as source for iframe using Visualforce email templates

Tags: email, email-template

I have a requirement where i have to use a force.com site(developed using Develop>sites) in email content.Please find below template and suggest.I tried but force.com site doesn't display in iframe.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="test" recipientType="Contact">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<apex:iframe src="https://forcesite-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/TakeSurvey?id=a002800000E7MnhAAF" scrolling="True" id="editSurvey" />  
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi gaurav, welcome to SF.SE. When you post code, after pasting it into your post, please select it and click on the `{}` pre-formatted text icon so that it's legible & visible to anyone who tries to read your post (yours was hidden). It's always a good practice to look at the preview pane of your post to fix any problems before posting it. Active content needs to be spaced over by 4 spaces or wrapped in backslashes or else the editor won't display it in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could include a link to your sites page if you want someone to take a survey as the link would seem to suggest. But the HTML from your sites page isn't going to display in an email since the email won't contain the HTML and the security on both your site (https) and the viewer's email client isn't going to allow an iframe to open active content from an unknown web site inside their email client. In your case, they'd also need to log-in to the site at a minimum as a guest.

If you want the content from the sites page to appear in your template, you'll need to copy and paste it into your template. If the content is linked to objects in your org, the HTML may not function properly if there's say a "submit" button that would require an https ajax action added to it submit data to a controller or page using web service if submitted outside your sites domain. Similar constraints would seem to apply to other content that might need to be securely served to the page from your sites domain in order to appear on the page.

I recommend you very thoroughly think through what it is that you're trying to accomplish with your email.